# If VCR catches javascript requests as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

My question is, if VCR also catches requests made on the client side ? Basically I'm using Stripe payments and want to catch checking card validation, which is made using my javascript but it uses external js functions, from file included from stripe site. Is it possible ?